# Put extension method in one file or in many files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, extension-methods

I use VS 2012 and I have some extension methods.

I want to know the best strategy to organize extension methods.

I can either create one file like `ExtensionMethods.cs` and put all of the extension methods inside or
create multiple `*.cs` files and put each method inside one file. Surely, some other ways may be assumed.

Here, I'm looking for nice and bright ideas.

Comment: I tend to organize extension methods by the type that extends.

Comment: +1 For nice and helpful question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the more important question is the static (non-generic) class where you want to put all the extension methods. It would be better if you can have related extension methods in a single static class and have a **single code file for each static class.**

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods must be defined within `static`, non-generic classes.

You can make as many such classes and files as you like.

Comment: The relationship between files and classes is many-to-many. In other words, you didn't answer the question.